# Почему при отправке email с адреса кириллицей сбивается кодировка?

Tags: php, кодировка, email

Отправляю почту через phpMailer:

```
$mail->From = "wordpress@имя-сайта.рф";
$mail->FromName = "Robot";
$mail->AddAddress($toEmail);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body = $template;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
if(!$mail->Send()) {
// ...
}
```

Все отправляется и отлично работает, но в некоторых почтовиках (например, mail.ru) появляется непонятная проблема: при корректной кодировке всего письма некоторые буквы из "имя-сайта.рф" не отображаются. Я бы понял, если бы не отображался весь адрес, но отдельные буквы... в итоге выглядит как-то так:
[image]

Совершенно не понимаю, куда копать в данной ситуации... буду благодарен любым советам, спасибо.

Comment: "wordpress@имя-сайта.рф"; - важно чтоб вот это было написано в UTF8, проверьте в вашем редакторе кодировку.

Comment: В том и проблема, что с кодировкой собственно файла (и его содержимого) все ок. Если кодировка не utf-8, не отображаются вообще все символы, что логично.

Comment: @Heian

> Если кодировка не utf-8, не отображаются вообще все символы, что логично.

Вообще не очень, 'wordpress' должен нормально проходить

@Manitikyl, там половина символов кодируется (полетели бы вообще все символы)

Comment: @Etki, спорить конечно не буду, но с точки теории - возможно.

Тогда единственное что посоветую, это при оправке письма посылать туда HEADER с Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: @Manitikyl, все однобайтовые кодировки используют для дополнительного charset'а значения от 128 до 255, или 1х хх хх хх (0х хх хх хх - стандартная ASCII-таблица). Юникод же не использует однобайтовые символы с первым проставленным битом вообще. Два идущих подряд байта в теории могут признаны верным символом, но для этого они должны удовлетворять условию 11 0х хх хх и 11 хх хх хх, в общем, маловероятно как-то совпадение. Там почему-то убивается последний символ перед тире и два после точки, с чего бы - я хз.